# How can i select all values from a nested dictionary with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

My `Super` class property is

```
public List<Test> Super { get; set; }
```

while my`Test` class is

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; }
}
```

How can i select all values from the dictionary where the key name is `"description"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to get all the dictionaries, for example:

```
var values = Super
    .SelectMany(s => s.dict)
    .Where(s => s.Key == "description")
    .Select(s => s.Value);
```

Comment: This does not make use of the O(1) lookup of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
var dict = (from p in obj.Super
                   where p.dict != null && p.dict.ContainsKey(keyToCheck)
                   select p.dict[keyToCheck]);
```

Complete code:

```
    void Main()
    {
        string keyToCheck = "description";
        var obj = new Super1();
        var dict = (from p in obj.Super
                   where p.dict != null && p.dict.ContainsKey(keyToCheck)
                   select p.dict[keyToCheck]);
        Console.Write(dict);
    }

    public class Super1
    {
        public List<Test> Super { get; set; } = new List<Test>(){
            new Test(){ Id = 1, dict = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
                {"description","abc"},{"description1","1"},{"description2","2"},{"description3","3"}
            }},
            new Test(){ Id = 2, dict = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
                {"description","xyz"},{"description4","4"},{"description5","5"},{"description6","6"}
            }
        }};
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> dict { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

```
abc 
xyz
```

Comment: Mixing Linq fluent and query syntax is a little bit awkward though.

Comment: removed off the lambda

Answer (score 0):

You can try is

```
List<string> AllValues = new List<string>();
Super.ForEach(x => 
      {
         if(x.dict.ContainsKey("description")
         {
             AllValues.AddRange(x.dict["description"]);
         } 
      });
```